# Strange padlock icon on status bar (not rotation-lock!)

Tags: jailbreak, ios

I recently noticed that a strange padlock icon with a "T" in it on my status bar. It is not rotation-lock tho. What exactly is this?

*iPhone 5s, iOS 7.0.6*

[image: strange padlock]

Comment: Is it there all the time, or does it ever disappear?

Comment: (Sorry about the many questions, I've just never seen this before either and knowing as much as possible about it increases our chances of figuring out what it is.)

Comment: It is there since it appeared, it never disappear even when I rebooted the device.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not on iOS 8?

Comment: Does it appear after you unlock the device ?

Comment: It still appears when the device is unlock, And the reason I didn't upgrade is because I like the Thai font in iOS 7.0, it later got removed in iOS 7.1 and later.

Comment: Is your device jailbroken by any chance ?

Comment: Yes, I think it was jailbroken by my cousin who restored it for me.

Comment: And you have a Twitter account on it :)

Comment: yes, I have 2 twitter accounts linked in my device settings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This icon does not appear in any of the devices running iOS 7 or 8.

It's probably caused by a jailbreak tweak. OpenNotifier is one such jailbreak tweak which lets you customise the status bar to indicate notifications from any app. The icon does not seem to relate to anything specific so it's quite impossible to tell what's it's indicating. Checking the tweak settings could tell what's that icon is indicating.

Comment: Actually you were close, you pointed me to the right direction. I took a look at libstatusbar's dependency and it turns out to be iAppLock's icon, which is new due to an update. Thank you anyways, I would not have figured it out without you.